# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Expression::whereColumn()

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Hay alguna forma de realizar esta consulta con eloquent?

```
SELECT 
      q.text, 
       (SELECT COUNT(*) 
          FROM tabla2 
         WHERE campo_id = q.id) total
  FROM tabla1 q;
```

Ya probé con:

```
$var = Tabla1::addSelect(['total' => Tabla2::raw('count(*)') 
            ->whereColumn('Tabla1.id', 'Tabla2.question_id')
     )->get();
```

Pero no me funcionó

Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Expression::whereColumn()

Comment: Si es asi, lo defini como $this->hasMany

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes resolverlo de forma simple si construyes una consulta de esta forma:

```
$conteoRespuestas = Modelo::withCount('relacion')->get();
```

Aprovechando las funcionalidades que nos brinda Eloquent a través de las relaciones que entre los modelos podemos definir (*partiendo del hecho que indicas ya tenerlas declaradas*) y los métodos disponibles para estas.

Donde:

- El modelo sería `Question`
- La relación (*asumiendo que asi se llama sería `answers`*)

De manera que obtengamos un conteo de las relaciones existentes para cada modelo recuperado, entonces la consulta se vería de esta forma:

```
$conteoRespuestas = Question::withCount('answers')->get();
```

**Referencia**

- [método `withCount`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#aggregating-related-models-related-models)

Comment: Excelente Amigo!. Gracias!